# Cannot delete record from MySQL. Error says column does not exist, when it clearly does

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is very strange..

I'm using PHPMyAdmin to view a table. [edit: Does the exact same thing in SQLYog.] I select one of the records in that table, and click "Delete".  I then get an error saying that the column (in this case "users_id" which is an auto-increment primary key) does not exist.  Yet.. when I run a select query for that same info, it returns the record fine.

So, here's the SELECT query I'm using that finds the record perfectly:

```
select * from users where users_id = 53
```

No quotes, nothing.  And it returns the record with no problem.  I would show you in a screen capture, but even though I have the reputation, the system isn't allowing me to post images. (ugh)

However, do this either by clicking "Delete" and "GO", or by entering SQL directly:

```
delete from users where users_id = 53
```

.. and you get an error:

```
Error
SQL query:

DELETE FROM `goat-dev`.`users` WHERE `users`.`users_id` =53

MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'users_id' in 'where clause'
```

So clearly something is off... and I just don't see what.  Any suggestions?

I'm logged in as "root" with full permissions.  I've quadruple-checked to be sure I have no limits on my permissions (not sure how root could).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. going to close this out.  Found the problem.  But left it up here for a moment to share the answer for the benefit of others.

There was a trigger that was not working properly.  The trigger was actually removing data from another table if a record in this table was deleted.  Apparently there was an error in that trigger.  Yet.. MySQL wasn't quoting the error - rather just throwing an error on this delete.  Kinda not well behaved.  But.. thought this may help someone else having this problem.

Hope this is at-least a little helpful.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings. I do not believe your question deserves deletion, instead you should be able to "accept" your own answer.